# How can I modifiy my c++ program to show a word inputted by a user, backwards using a stack?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stack, character-arrays

I want to assign a pointer to every character the user inputs. Then in doing so, I probably can use a loop to store the characters and a second loop rearrange the stack order using the pointers. But I don't know how to write that in a program form, and I'm not sure if it can work. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Stack{
public:
  enum {MaxStack = 50};
  void init() {top = -1;}
  void push( char n ){
    if ( isFull() ) {
      cerr << "Full Stack. DON'T PUSH\n";
      return;
    }
    else {
      arr[ ++top ] = n;
      cout << "Just pushed " << n << endl;
      return;}
  }
  int pop() {
    if (isEmpty() ) {
      cerr << "\tEmpty Stack. Don't Pop\n\n";
      return 1;
    }
    else 
      return arr[top--];
  }
  bool isEmpty() {return top < 0 ? 1 : 0;}
  bool isFull() {return top >= MaxStack -1 ? top : 0;}
  void dump_stack() {
    cout << "The Stack contents, from top to bottom, from a stack dump are: " << endl;
    for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--)
      cout << "\t\t" << arr[i] << endl;
  }
private:  
  int top;
  int arr[MaxStack];
};

int main()
{   

    Stack a_stack;
    int x = 0;
    char inputchar;


    cout<<"Please enter a word"<<endl;
  a_stack.init();

while (inputchar != '.') //terminating char
 {
 cin >> inputchar;
 array[x] = inputchar;
 x++;
 }

int j = x;

for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
 {
 cout << array[x];
 x--;
 }
  a_stack.push();

  a_stack.dump_stack();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need an intermediate `array `, directly push `inputchar`to stack. You also don't need your own `stack`class, use one from `std`

Comment: There's no reason to use a stack for this (unless this is an assignment...): `int main(){cout<<"enter word: ";std::string s;cin>>s;std::reverse(std::begin(s),std::end(s));cout<<s<<'\n';}`

Answer (score 1):

A stack, by its very LIFO nature (Last In, First Out), will reverse the order of anything you put in it.  Example for string "Hello":

(The top of the stack is to the left)

```
H        push "H"
eH       push "e"
leH      push "l"
lleH     push "l"
olleH    push "o"
```

Now when you pop from the stack, you'll first get "o", then "l", etc. It's whatever you put in but in reverse order. You don't need to do anything special to achive that. Just push to stack in normal order, and when you pop you'll get it reversed:

```
// while loop
{
    cin >> inputchar;
    a_stack.push(inputchar);
}

// Display in reverse
while (not a_stack.isEmpty()) {
    cout << (char)a_stack.pop();
}
```

Here's a small example program using `std::stack`:
(No input error checking is done here.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

int main()
{
    std::stack<char> st;
    char c = '\0';
    while (c != '.') {
        c = std::cin.get();
        st.push(c);
    }

    while (not st.empty()) {
        std::cout << st.top();
        st.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Example input and output:

```
Hello world.
.dlrow olleH
```

Comment: I was thinking about doing that way. Manually pushing characters into the stack but it doesn't account for if the user were to enter their own word. And my professor made it seem like if you pop members out the stack...it's deleting them from memory, so I was wondering how would it display it. I know a super simple way, which is to have the user enter different characters then I would place it within the stack myself, and when the user is finished I give the user the option to end their input and display their word in reverse. Considering that their is not a word longer than 30 or 40. letters

Comment: @TravisD. I don't see the problem. You only start popping from the stack *after* the user finished with their input. So their complete input will be reversed.

Comment: @TravisD. I updated my answer with a small example program to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: Wow now I feel stupid, smh. I was making something so simple, seem complicating. I was having difficulty with my syntax especially with the stack function, so I cleaned it up and submitted it. Thanks a lot Nikos. Ironically, today my professor just taught us the "null terminating character" and "cin.get()."

Answer (score 0):

Unless using a stack is a must (i.e. it is a homework), you might be better off with `getline()`, its parameter `delim` (cf  [getline](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/)) followed by a reverse loop over the array. It would be faster, cleaner, less prone to errors and basically a two-liner.

Comment: No I seen a get cin.getline example on here where it is used in a recursive form but my professor said we must use a stack :(